# Install own Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay, I'm making a hello world gem called dogify, but I can't install it in my demo project.

Here's my gemspec, please ask for any other files:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'my_dogify/version'
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "my_dogify"
  spec.version       = MyDogify::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ['me']
  spec.email         = ['me']
  spec.summary       = 'summmary'
  spec.description   = 'description'
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.7"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency 'rspec'

  spec.add_dependency 'engtagger'
end
```

Here's my Gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'my_dogify'
```

Command line:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'my_dogify (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Comment: You have to specify the path to the local gem you have built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, gems are searched in the RubyGems repository. That means in order to use `my_dogify` it must be [published on RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/search?query=my_dogify).

If you don't care about publishing it and you just want to use it locally, then [use the `path` option](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) to specify the path to the gem.

```
gem 'extracted_library', :path => './vendor/extracted_library'
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Just to help others, the path should be the root folder of you gem. So for me it was gem `'extracted_library', :path => 'dogify'`